On my network profile one of my questions in "Top Questions" has a tag that was never on the question
This question of mine on Law.se has the tags "enforcing-judgment" and "contempt-of-court".

But on my network profile it also has "multiple-jurisdiction".

The question has no edit history so I don't see how it can have had that tag. However the "extra" tag does fit the question and I can see myself adding it when I wrote the question.
So is this a bug or is there a way to remove a tag without creating an edit history?

The [multiple-jurisdiction] tag doesn't seem to exist on Law.SE: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-jurisdiction

And my hesitance to use all 5 tags has allowed Spevacus to show us that adding tags does indeed create an edit history haha

I even removed a tag and made another revision entry. I'm crazy like that.

I think I found what happened:

I can see myself adding it when I wrote the question

You probably did. The tag has since been removed, see the discussion on Meta Law: Should we remove [multiple-jurisdiction] along with [any-jurisdiction]?
Specifically, this was not the regular burnination, which is simply users going through questions with a given tag and editing them. From the answer by staff member Sasha:

The [multiple-jurisdiction] tag has been bulk removed and blocked, per the consensus reached on this post.

(emphasis mine)
It was a system-level action that removed the tag. However, the entry you see on the network profile is probably cached.

It might have been on the question. According to this tag burnination request: Should we remove [multiple-jurisdiction] along with [any-jurisdiction]?, this tag was removed by staff. Presumably their removal tools work the databases directly, without touching edit histories.
